# Как подобное реализуется? (js, input)

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы показатели "от" и "до" зависели от положения маркеров.

Comment: Например через плагин для jQuery – http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: как к нему input`ы привязать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, помогла эта библиотека: http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/